# How to bypass current page on GET request method in Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

For example, I'm currently on **/users** page and when I'm sending request from that page it refers to **/users/conversations/id** while I need just **conversations/id**. How to do so?

**users.js**

```
$('.start-conversation').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var sender_id = $(this).data('sid');
    var recipient_id = $(this).data('rip');

    $.post("/conversations", { sender_id: sender_id, recipient_id: recipient_id }, function (data) {
        chatBox.chatWith(data.conversation_id);
    });
});
```

**chat.js**

```
   $.get("conversations/" + conversation_id, function (data) {
                $('#chatbox_' + conversation_id).html(data);
                $("#chatbox_" + conversation_id + " .chatboxcontent").scrollTop($("#chatbox_" + conversation_id + " .chatboxcontent")[0].scrollHeight);
            }, "html");
```

[image]

Comment: You want an absolute path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a relative path: `"conversations/" + conversation_id`, relative paths will get appended to the current path.

You want to use an absolute path instead. Since you want `/conversations/id` just add `/` to the front of your path

```
$.get("/conversations/" + conversation_id
```